# Scala "bad symbolic reference" to scala.actors

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, compilation

I am trying to compile a Java / Scala project in Intellij and getting the following error:

Error:scalac: Error: bad symbolic reference to scala.actors encountered in class file 'Anytime.class'.
Cannot access term actors in package scala. The current classpath may be
missing a definition for scala.actors, or Anytime.class may have been compiled against a version that's
incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.
scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: bad symbolic reference to scala.actors encountered in class file 'Anytime.class'.
Cannot access term actors in package scala. The current classpath may be
missing a definition for scala.actors, or Anytime.class may have been compiled against a version that's
incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.

```
at scala.reflect.internal.pickling.UnPickler$Scan.toTypeError(UnPickler.scala:675)
```

The Scala source code is mixed with the Java source code. I don't understand what is causing this error or how to fix it.

Comment: Can you post your build file?

Comment: I don't have a build file. I'm using Intellij IDEA, its an IDE. Are you talking about the big compile string that appears in the console when I build?

Comment: it's not a good practice to use IDE as build tool. try to use [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/). it has idea support and simple to begin with

Comment: You are probably mixing incompatible versions of libraries or libraries not compatible with the Scala version you are compiling for. If you post the compile string as you suggested we may be able to see which libraries are actually conflicting / broken.